# Uncaught Reference Error:_______ is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner with limited knowledge of both Javascript and html, sorry if my questions are very basic.
I'm trying to write a basic webpage that will do something to an array using Javascript when a button is clicked, then print the result to the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
//error here
<html>
<head>
<title>Thursday's Homework</title>
<script>
    var problem1 = function() 
    {for (var i = 0; i <= 50; i += 5) {
        document.write(i + " ");
        }
    }   
    var myArray = []
    var problem2 = function()
        {for (var i = 0; i <= 9; ++i){
            myArray[i]
            }
        document.write(myArray)     
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><h2><b> My Homework for Thursday<b></h2></center>
<p>This is my code for Problem 1:</p>
<input type="button" onclick = "problem1()" value="Does it work?">
//error here
<p>This is my code for Problem 2:</p>
<input type="button" onclick = "problem2()" value="Does it work?">
//error here
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting three error messages when I debug in Chrome using developer tools:
After line 1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
After line 22(the first button): Uncaught ReferenceError: problem1 is not defined
After line 24(the second button): Uncaught Reference Error: problem2 is not defined

I'm also wondering if there's a better way to display the outputs than `document.write` because that makes it so that the page needs to be reloaded each time to see the next result.

I'm new, so my apologies if this is completely the wrong way to create this whole thing. If that's the case, just point me in the right direction.

UPDATE:
I've fixed the syntax errors and it's running fine. I'm still wondering about a better way to display my result that `document.write`. I'm not too knowledgeable, so if you have a suggestion, could you give me an idea of how to implement it?

Comment: you're not closing the problem2 function

Answer (score 2):

> You are missing a closing } after problem2.

That is the most common cause for this kind of error. The JS interpreter breaks since the function body is not properly closed, stops parsing. Then something else tries to reference a variable/function that failed to get parsed and triggers the Reference Error.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few issues.

1. You are missing a closing `}` after `problem2`.
2. You have spaces around your `=` for `onclick =`.
3. You're not actually doing anything with myArray. That does not seem intentional.
4. Your code formatting is unclear and that can lead to difficulties later (and I think this, in part, caused the bug). Unless you have a particularly good reason you should avoid things like `{for`. Instead add a newline after the `{`.

Comment: Yeah I was so hesitant to put this as an answer because it looks like it is just wrong in structure to begin with and I didn't really want to write out a better way to do... whatever it is he's doing here. Plusses just to keep you safe

Comment: Thanks, I caught 1 and 3 after comments above and some looking. I missed 2, thanks for it.
Yeah, I forgot to put what I wanted myArray to do, i've got it now.

Answer (score 0):

1. close the brace of problem2();
2. instead of document.write(); u can specify a id like

   or

and in the js use

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML=i+" ";
```

for better and safer coding use jsLint ..

Answer (score 0):

As for you second question, you can find a lot of helpful extensions for both Chrome and Firefox that can satisfy you for debugging.

Chrome has internal tools such as "Web Console" that allow you to watch variables for exemple.